# How to implement address search (react-geocoder?) in combination with react-map-gl (DeckGL)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, geocode

I'd like to add an address search bar to automatically zoom to a specific location (similar to https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder/) in my DeckGL data visualization. The visualization is based on the http://vis.academy/ Geospatial App template, which uses webpack and react-map-gl.

I succeeded in adding the react-geocoder https://github.com/mapbox/react-geocoder, after loading the package as ES2015, with 
`import Geocoder from 'react-geocoder'`

I am not sure however, how to translate the ES2015 example file in the react-geocoder package (https://github.com/mapbox/react-geocoder/blob/master/example/site.js) to ES2016 and how to integrate it into the DeckGL Geospatial App code.

When I follow an approach similar to the app.js Root class or the deckgl-overlay.js of the Geospatial App template I get this error, which I have not been able to resolve, even after trying suggested solutions for this particular problem:

> Cannot read property '__reactAutoBindMap' of undefined

Anyone any idea how to integrate react-geocoder or another address search option with automatic zooming to the specified location with the DeckGL Geospatial App example?

Comment: Did you find a solution at last?

Comment: Unfortunately no solution yet. May look into it again at a later time.